# Why does expr fail when matching a single 0

Tags: bash, expr

The following command works:

```
$ expr 1 : '\(.\)' || echo fail
1
```

When trying to match the string "0" the command fails, e.g. $? == 1:

```
$ expr 0 : '\(.\)' || echo fail
fail
```

The man page says:

> Exit status is 0 if EXPRESSION is neither null nor 0

But, returning exit status 1 because the matching string is 0 does not make sense.

Comment: `expr` shouldn't be used in bash code at all; it's an artifact of the 1970s, and not part of the shell at all (invoking it starts a separate executable, `/usr/bin/expr`).

Comment: ...if you want to use bash's built-in regex code, `[[ 1 =~ (.) ]]` is the alternative -- and its behavior is more sensible (evaluates as truthy if there's a match, even if its content is `0`).

Comment: @DagLöwenvald : I don't know what is the intended purpose of your statement, but for all digits `d`, `expr $d : '\(.\)'` write $d to stdout. Hence, the exit status is 1 if `d=0`, and 0 for other values of `d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit status of `expr` depends on the string returned, not the operation that produces that string.

> ```
>  The expr utility exits with one of the following values:
>  0       the expression is neither an empty string nor 0.
>  1       the expression is an empty string or 0.
>  2       the expression is invalid.
> ```

Since the returned string is 0, the exit status is 1.

Whether you use a successful regular expression match or some other operator to produce the 0 isn't relevant.

```
$ expr 3 - 3 || echo "fail"
0
fail
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like expr just evaluates `0` as an error case:

```
$ expr 1
$ echo $?
0

$ expr 0
$ echo $?
1
```